# cookie for 1 hour but after refreshing the page , the timer wil start again

Tags: php, session, cookies

I am working in a PHP language . I am making on a website. In my sign-in page, after checking the user has input the correct information. I want to store the `id` and `name` in session or cookie so that I can use them in my other pages but I don't know which one is secure and useful. I have read  so many questions but I didn't got my answer. Which one is better **COOKIE** and **SESSION**.

And I want to make to cookie for **1 hour** but if the user refreshes the page, the time will start again.

```
setcookie("registration",true,time()+3600,'/');
```

The cookie I have made above, will do the required work which I want?

Comment: Cookies are stored at client, while session on server. To access session client still keeps token in cookies so attacker still will be able to hijack session if steals cookies, so you'll need to regenerate session token every time privileges are changed. Actually, this is quite large topic and can't be covered here completely. Anyway, I am not a guy who is able to cover it though.

Comment: To point your issue: _on every page timer restarts fr cookie (in another words, expiration date resets)_, this happens because you reset cookies every-time. Once it is set, it should not reset. For example, `if (!isset($_COOKIES['registration'])) { setcookie("registration",true,time()+3600,'/'); }`

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer session,

With cookies, everything is stored on the client's side, and goes on the network for each page and can be :

- modified by the user
- sniffed by anyone, if not using HTTPS

With sessions, everything (except the session identifier, of course) is stored on the server, which means it can only be modified by your code, and not by the user, who doesn't even see what's there.

you can use,

```
$seconds = 60*60;
$_SESSION['timeout'] = time() + $seconds;
```

You can check as,

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['timeout'])) {
    $timeDiffernce = time() - $_SESSION['timeout'];
    if ($timeDiffernce > 3600) { // exprie after one hour (3600 seconds)
        // unset session
        unset($_SESSION['username']);
        unset($_SESSION['password']);
        unset($_SESSION['timeout']);

        // get login form
} else {
    // do your session code
}
```